# Parse and Facebook Login creating an empty user

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

now that Parse belongs to Facebook's family I hope you can help me to find a quick solution to my problem.

My app crashes sometimes when a user logs in for the first time thru Facebook, the reason of this crash is that for some reason (and I say it again) SOMETIMES this user is created empty on parse's data base, it only gets an Auth Data, and every other field is empty, so when I get the parseUser its completely empty and everything  crashes. I know I could validate everything so it won't crash, but my question is WHY IS THIS HAPPENING? AND WHY IT DOESN'T HAPPENS ALWAYS? I am requesting al permissions and all the info that I need from the user in my code.

This is the whole method that I am using: I really hope someone can help me:

```
func fbLogin (successBlock:(result:User) -> () , errorBlock: (error:String) -> ())  {

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(kFbPermissions, block: {

        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let user = user {

            if user.isNew {

                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")

                FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                    var loggedUser = User(result: result,aParseObject: user)
                            loggedUser.saveUser()
                            appDelegate.loggedUser = loggedUser
                            successBlock (result: loggedUser
                    })
                })
            } else {

                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                var loggedUser = User(aParseObject: user)
                appDelegate.loggedUser = loggedUser
                println (appDelegate.loggedUser!.objectId)
                successBlock(result: loggedUser)
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
            errorBlock (error: localizedStringForKey("loginCanceled"))
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: The mere fact that you _request_ permissions, does not necessarily mean that the user _grants_ all of them to your app. I’d suggest you log the access token in such cases, and then debug it to see what permissions it contains, or alternatively make a request for `/me/permissions` to see what permissions were granted and which ones might have been declined.

Comment: Thanks for you input and I hate to bother you, but do you mind explaining how can I do this with some code? This is my first "big app" and I don't have much experience. @CBroe